# Linking Facebook with Google account having same email Id with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to setup a login page for my app and want to give the user the option of logging in with Email/Password, Facebook and Google. I am able to successfully login and logout with each of the method successfully. I want to link all the accounts from different Auth providers with same email address. I was going through firebase docs, and went through the linkwithcredential. Firebase tells to use linkwithcredential after signing in with any of the signin methods if I understand correctly. In my case if I logged in the user via facebbok first->user logs out->signs in with google->invoke linkwithcredential(my expectation is that facebook gets linked at this ). Is my understanding wrong?Else how do i sign in a user smoothly using different auth providers without requesting any action from user. Please help

```
private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

    final AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());

    firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        linkCredential(credential);
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ProfileActivity.class));

                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.d("***facebook fail", task.getException().toString());
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());

                        if(task.getException().toString().equals(getResources().getString(R.
                                string.fb_login_google))){

                            FirebaseUser mUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"User already signed in via google",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            Log.d("***facebook failure ","failed");
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });
}

    public void linkCredential(AuthCredential credential){

    Log.d("shitttttt" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser(),credential.toString());


    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "linkWithCredential:success");

                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "linkWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "linkWithCredential:failure",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });

    //final AuthCredential fbCredential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken());

    Log.d("fbcredential",credential.toString());
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly ı dont think there is a way spereate them.I also using email/password and google auth system together.If email is same firebase automatically gives same uid.

Comment: @UzaySan In that case, if I am now logged in with google, and I already logged with Facebook previously then I should get the token from AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), but it is returning null for me.